# How to make a custom command available in sftp

Tags: command-line, sftp

There are only [few commands](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sftp.1.html) available in `sftp` environment. Is it possible to make available any custom command in `sftp`.

For example any other executable (that is not available by default), or any shell script or alias.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: No. And I would advice using ssh.

Answer (score 2):

You're treating SFTP and SSH as if they're the same.
That's your problem here; they aren't the same.

SFTP is very deliberately locked down for handling files and nothing else.

The only way I can imagine doing what you suggest is by replacing `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` with something else that does support a remote command syntax. I don't know any drop-in replacements that will. You would also need a client that knew what to do... This is asking a lot.

I'd suggest using SSH (if you have access) when you need to fire commands off. It can also do [some limited file moving](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13382/download-a-file-over-an-active-ssh-session) but that's really not what it's for.

Comment: I agree with you, just wanted to know if there is any out. Thanks +1 for the intuitive sggestion