# Escape code sequence for copying file content

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

I found from [here](https://medium.com/free-code-camp/tmux-in-practice-integration-with-system-clipboard-bcd72c62ff7b) that you can use ANSCI Escape sequence to copy from a remote ssh session like so,

```
printf "\033]52;c;$(printf "%s" "blabla" | base64)\a"
```

I have tried issuing command,

```
$ (file=README.md; printf "\033]52;c;$(base64 $file)\a")
```

But I am able to print only the first few characters (~57 characters). Is there a way to copy the whole content of a file with the Escape sequence?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not just [using `scp` to copy the files](https://askubuntu.com/a/646448)?

Comment: It would be more convenient since I am usually in an interactive session.

Comment: you are missing the %s specifier on the first `printf`

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/13586/1438484). It looks like it does what you want, and looks far easier @bac0n Mind posting that like an answer? It looks like it would be a good one!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the output printed to the clipboard you may use `xclip`

```
xclip -sel -p -i < <( \
 printf %s%s%s '\033]52;c;' "$(printf %s blabla | base64)" '\a' \
)
```

Comment: The downside is that the ssh server does not have X Window running.

Comment: @phoxd but your client does?

Comment: Well, I am trying copy from a remote server. No point to run on my local machine.